# Python Blackjack game - referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.4, blackjack

So, my personal challenge is to make a simple Blackjack game in python. This is the way I've gone about doing it:

```
singlePlayerCard = random.choice(availableCards)
singlePlayerCard2 = random.choice(availableCards)

if(singlePlayerCard == [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]):
    singlePlayerCardValue = singlePlayerCard

if(singlePlayerCard2 == [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]):
    singlePlayerCard2Value = singlePlayerCard2


singlePlayerCardValueTotal = singlePlayerCardValue+singlePlayerCard2Value
print ("The total of your card values is %i"%singlePlayerCardValueTotal)
```

When it comes to print the `singlePlayerCardValueTotal` it tells me either that `singlePlayerCardValue` or `singlePlayerCard2Value` has been referenced before assignment. It's confused me slightly as I've had this issue in the past with another simple program I made but the structure is different here. Apart from the aforementioned issue, it was working fine. Also if you have the time, please inform me of any better solutions to some areas if necessary.

As always, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Do you understand what "referenced before assignment" means?

Comment: @Blorgbeard from past attempts at other programs, I've learnt that it means I've mentioned it in the code, before it has actually been given a value

Comment: Yep, so it looks like none of your `if` statements hit, so you never assigned anything to `singlePlayerCardValue`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Hmm, I understand why I'm getting the error (because the `if` statements aren't working), but I'm not sure why the `if` statements aren't working. I was a little hesitent when writing them, I've never before had one `if` statement after the other, normally I have an `elif` or `else` afterwards.

Comment: @Blorgbeard checking your answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted in your comment, "referenced before assignment" means that you've mentioned a variable before it's been given a value.

It looks like your problem is this:

```
if(singlePlayerCard == [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]):
    singlePlayerCardValue = singlePlayerCard
```

Since your `singlePlayerCard` is never **equal to** the list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`, you will not assign a value to the variable when it's a number card.

The `==` operator is not the way to check whether a list contains a value. Try this, instead:

```
if(singlePlayerCard in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]):
    singlePlayerCardValue = singlePlayerCard
```

Comment: Thanks very much, now you've explained it, I can see why it wasn't working. Thanks very much for the solution and thanks also for testing my knowledge on the referenced before assignment. I guess if gave you an idea as to how knowledgeable I was before making the answer. Good idea! Thanks again for the solution! Ticked!